# Waiting for all asynchronous consumers to complete before producer continues

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

We have a problem set that is very close to the producer-consumer problem. The actual use case is for a thread (producer) that runs through a directory listing (approx. 2000 entries), then feeds these entries to 4 threads (consumers) that processes specific files in those directories.

The problem we are attempting to resolve is how to make the producer thread wait for the final consumer to complete before continuing on. There is post-processing required once we have all the files in memory that can only be done once all the files have been read.

We have implemented a very naive counter solution based on a busy wait that polls a class counter (counter incremented by producer, decremented by consumer, protected by a mutex):

```
   while(fileCnt > 0) {
     usleep(10000);
  }
```

This is of cause not a nice soltion.

Is there any way of doing this via conditionals/semaphores/something else?

We are limited to non-C++11 implementations (pthread based).

Thanks.

Comment: These consumers are being fed by a queue that is cv+mtx protected and who's content size is part of the predicate check, is that right?

Comment: The typical method is to have a semaphore, and pre-load the semaphore with the queue-size (e.g. 4, 5 or 8, to allow the producer to have some items ready for the consumer). Then up and down on the semaphore is used to indicate the amount of space left, and when the semaphore is zero, it waits for the other side to consume the next item)

Comment: @WhozCraig "We are limited to non-C++11 implementations (pthread based)." --- Unless you are suggesting the boost variants.

Comment: What other libraries you are allowed to use ? Boost/ RogueWave ?

Comment: @Jagannath who said anything about c++11 ? Standard `pthreads.h` has both condition variables and mutexes. *What are you talking about*? At no time did I ignore the OP's restriction on no C++11 specifics.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry. I am not aware that pthreads.h have condition variables .

Comment: Do the consumer threads need to live past the end of this processing?  If not, you can simply "join" them.

Comment: @WhozCraig - yes, fed via a queue. Only info they are given is the directory to operate on.

Comment: @Mats Petersson - yes, only difference being that we don't want to limit the queue, so no "max". This actually runs on a device where disk IO is extremely expensive compared to memory. Hence we queue as much as possible.

Comment: @Jagannath - would prefer a non-library solution as including boost just to solve this seems overkill (but would consider it if required).

Comment: @John Zwinck - threads live on. They live until the system comes down. It might be an option to bring them down and respawn when the operation has been completed. Thanks.

Comment: If the 'bringing down and respawning' can be avoided, you should definitely avoid it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. this is actually quite difficult to do in an efficient manner for a general case.  If you know before submitting your first entry how many objects you are going to submit to the queue, (as you seem to do), it's easier:

Set an atomic integer to the number of objects to be submitted.  Load a callback in each item queued that the threads call when they have finished processing each object. The callback decrements the int towards zero.  When a thread decs it to zero, it signals a synchro object upon which the producer is waiting after queueing its last object.

I'm still thinking about what to do if the producer is iterating some list and does not know where the end is before queueing its first item:(

That case may require an actual lock in the callback so that the producer can enter it and check 'atomically' if all the queued operations are finished yet and, if not, wait on the synchro object after exiting the lock.  It's safer if the synchro object maintains state, eg. a semaphore, so that a signal made after exiting the lock, but before the waiting, is not missed, (?? not sure how to do it safely with a condvar??).

Comment: We implemented the above using 2 mutex objects and it works rather well. Thanks.

Comment: I had implemented this very solution, and came here in search of a better solution. If you have 100 threads decrementing the atomic int, you also have 100 if's to do, of which only one will return true and signal back tot he producer, thats 99 if's that will return False for sure, we just don't know which. I can't think of a better solution, ideas?

Comment: It's 99 decs with a jump on zero for the check.  It's nothing really:)   Firing the callback will take more cycles than the check.